# Keep iPhone and iCloud Photos In-Sync

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

Is it possible to keep the photos on the iPhone and iCloud in-sync? So if I delete a photo on the iPhone, I want it to be deleted on iCloud and vice versa.

Is it possible to configure the phone/cloud to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you enable iCloud Photos on the iPhone, your iCloud photo library and the iPhone's photo library will automatically be synchronized. Then if you delete a photo on the iPhone, the same photo in the iCloud library will automatically be deleted.

You'll find the guide for turning on iCloud Photos here:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204264